# Regex filter items in list to have only those items which DO contain a character that isn't a-z

Tags: python, regex, alphanumeric

I have tried so many regex combinations that I am unsure if the problem is my regex or my python coding (being fairly new to both).

I have a `list` called `inputs`:

```
inputs = [':boy', '_144-', '_1445', '_1445', 'alpha', 'monkey', '#sdakm', '.file', '.magic']
```

I want to end up with a `list` that contains only those items which **do** have a non-alphabetic character (unknown) in them.

So I want to find:

```
newlist = [':boy', '_144-', '_1445', '#sdakm', '.file', '.magic']
```

without the items that are all [a-z]. I also want to filter out any duplicate matches (of any type).

My python code is as follows:

```
import os, sys, re, string, codecs, cchardet, chardet

inputs = [':boy', '_144-', '_1445', '_1445', 'alpha', 'monkey', '#sdakm', '.file', '.magic']

regex = re.compile('.*[^abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz]*.*')
myset = set()
inputs_filtered=[]
for inp in inputs:
    if re.search(i,inp):
        if inp not in myset:
            inputs_filtered.append(inp)
            print('adding' + inp)
            myset.add(inp)
            ofile.write(inp + '\n')
        else:
            print('removing duplicate ' + inp)
    else:
        print("IS ALL LETTERS " + i)
print(myset)
ofile.close()
```

regex I have tried either to filter out or keep (I have tried so many different ways including different codes using things like:

```
[filter(lambda i: regex.search(i), inputs)]

'\".*[\W|\.|_|\_|-|\-]*.*\"

'.*[^abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz]*.*'

'\"[\w]*\",?'

'[\w]*'
```

Another thing to not is that `myset.add()` seems to be producing an empty set yet for some odd reason `inputs_filtered` is being populated...I think.

Comment: The regex that matches a character which is not a-z is `[^a-z]`. Search just for it, you can throw away the `.*` at the sides.

Comment: Inside a character class `[...]` the `|` is seen as a literal character and doesn't mean `OR`. Also, many special characters that needs to be escaped in a pattern don't need to be escaped inside a character class; in particular the dot. The underscore and the double quote don't need to be escaped at all (inside or outside a character class).

Comment: Thank you guys, especially the insight about | and OR. That is something that I would never have known.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using set in your example, it appears that the order of results do not matter.
You can do this easily 2 ways. One with regex and the other without regex (why bother with regex when you don't have to).

With regex, you just need a simple regex `[^a-z]`. With the use of `filter` you can do the following:

```
# drop the IGNORECASE option if you only want lowercase
pat = re.compile(r'[^a-z]', re.IGNORECASE)

# using the function pat.search as your filter function
results = set(filter(pat.search, inputs))
```

If it suits your case, there is a function on the `str` class named `isalpha` that returns true if your string has only alpha characters. You can build your set using the following code:

```
results = { word for word in inputs if not word.isalpha() }
```

If you include the `filterfalse` function from `itertools` (the counterpoint of `filter`), you can do the following:

```
from itertools import filterfalse
results = set(filterfalse(str.isalpha, inputs))
```

You can consider writing your own function to use with `filter`. Here's a function that also excludes colons or spaces:

```
def has_valid_characters(word):
    return not (word.isalpha() or 
                ' ' in word or 
                ':' in word)
# ...
results = set(filter(has_valid_characters, input))
```

If there are a bunch of other characters you'd want to exclude, you can use a regex or use the `any` function as part of your filter function:

```
def has_valid_characters_no_regex(word):
    return not (word.isalpha() or
                any(x in word for x in ' :#-'))

pat2 = re.compile('[- :#]')

def has_valid_characters_regex(word):
    return not (word.isalpha() or
                pat2.search(word))
```

Comment: Great so many useful things here. How would I modify your code if I also wanted to **exclude** any list items that included a colon (:) or white space in them?

Comment: @lgjmac Added to the original answer.

Comment: Thank you! Please upvote me, I've lost my question rights:((( I promise I'll try harder!!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `re.findall` with `\W`:

```
inputs = [':boy', '_144-', '_1445', '_1445', 'alpha', 'monkey', '#sdakm', '.file', '.magic']
final_inputs = list(filter(lambda x:re.findall('[\W_]', x), inputs))
```

Output:

```
[':boy', '_144-', '_1445', '_1445', '#sdakm', '.file', '.magic']
```

Comment: Both brilliant answers that helped me understand different things. I can only accept one! But I really wanted to say thank you Ajax as well.

Answer (score 1):

You have a `*` after `[^abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz]` which means match that 0 or more repetitions. Change it to a `+` so that means match it 1 or more repetitions.

You can abbreviate `[^abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz]` to `[^a-z]`.

```
>>> regex = re.compile('.*[^a-z]+.*')
>>> list(filter(lambda s: regex.match(s), inputs))
[':boy', '_144-', '_1445', '_1445', '#sdakm', '.file', '.magic']
```

Comment: If that works, you may just use `list(filter(lambda s: re.search(r'[^a-z]', s), inputs))`

Answer (score 0):

You can also try without regex approach :

```
inputs = [':boy', '_144-', '_1445', '_1445', 'alpha', 'monkey', '#sdakm', '.file', '.magic']


import unicodedata
import sys

symbols=[chr(i) for i in range(sys.maxunicode) if unicodedata.category(chr(i)).startswith('P')]


print([j for i in symbols for j in inputs if i in j])
```

output:

```
['#sdakm', '_144-', '.file', '.magic', ':boy', '_144-', '_1445', '_1445']
```